# How to solve Gaussian Elimination?

Tags: matlab, binary-operations, gaussian-elimination

I have matrix solved as-

```
1 1 1 0 | 1
0 1 0 1 | 1
0 0 1 1 | 0
0 0 0 1 | 0
```

Now I can solve it as

```
for i = n : -1 : 1  % go back from n to 1
    x(i) = bitand(dot(mat(i, i:n), x(i:n)) + mat(i, n + 1), 1);
end

   % where n = size of a matrix (column) 
   %       x() =  zeros
```

But actually I have the matrix in the decimal format like -

```
14 | 1
5  | 1
3  | 0
1  | 0
```

Now how do I solve it?

Comment: Split the binary representation.

Comment: How can I do it in Decimal format? I don't want to convert back into binary format

Comment: Sorry, you can't.